I need correct library setup to make a Python connection to DB2
I am on Windows 11, Python 3.12.2 installed. After many failures of my script to connect to DB2 after installing ibm_db I noted that a milestone is to get a connection using just db2cli which is independent of Python and make it work. Then supposedly I would be home free by just using the connection string that the 'validate' command generated from DB2CLI. I finally got DB2CLI VAlIDATE to work and make a connection to DB2 on the mainframe. But plugging the resultant connection string into my Python still did not succeed.
The string is as shown from the successful connection with db2cli:
Connection attempt for data source name "xxxxxxxx":
===============================================================================

[SUCCESS]

Output Connection String :
"DSN=xxxxxxxx;UID=LIDDVDP;PWD=********;DATABASE=xxxxxxxx;HOSTNAME=xxxxxxxx;PORT=447;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;SECURITY=SOCKETS;"

===============================================================================
The validation is completed.
=============================================================================== 

I have a path loop in my Python which I show below that displays all my attempts to get a correct PATH so that Python could duplicate the db2cli validate success but no luck:
C:\Users\liddvdp\pylib
C:\Highmarkapps\Python3.12.2
C:\Highmarkapps\Python3.12.2\Lib\idlelib
C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\python312.zip
C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\DLLs
C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\Lib
C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2
C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\Lib\site-packages
C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\amd64.VC12.CRT
C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\icc64
C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\C_Highmarkapps_Python3.12.2_Lib_site-packages_clidriver\cfg
IBM_DB_HOME

The error msg never changes, it is:
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004  SQLCODE=-1042

Does anyone have any ideas on corrections are needed ??

Looks like db2 was no shutdown gracefully. Also here

I found a solution to the connection issue....I added 'AUTHORIZATION=SERVER' to the connnection string and amazingly after two weeks of labor....it worked !!!!
